# Where can I learn more about R's build options?

Tags: c, r, lapack, blas

When building R from source, http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Other-Options directs me to `./configure --help` which lists 200 lines of flags I "might potentially" want to use:

`--enable-strict-barrier`, `--enable-lto`, `--with-lapack`, `--with-blas`, `--with-system-zlib`, `--with-system-tre`, `--with-internal-tzcode`, `--with-x`, ….

Since the manual doesn't have much information about a lot of these options, where should I go to learn about them?

Comment: Read the compiler documentation.

Comment: @BondedDust `man g++` doesn't contain for example any mention of `internal-tzcode`, `blas`, `zlib` …

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=internal-tzcode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb

Comment: @BondedDust My question is if there's somewhere that explains more about these various options centrally, rather than having to google each of them individually, which is what I'm doing right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* answered in the manual, just in a different part of the manual (appendices).

- Linear algebra (BLAS, LAPACK, ATLAS) is documented in [another part of the R manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Linear-algebra).
- Useful blog comments [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/2013/07/09/for-faster-r-use-openblas-instead-better-than-atlas-trivial-to-switch-to-on-ubuntu/#comment-3963) and [here](http://andrewgelman.com/2008/06/22/a_trick_to_spee/#comment-45580) regarding BLAS.
- `zlib`, `pcre`, `xz`, `bzlib` are discussed in [another part of the R manual](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-admin/R-admin_57.html)
- `gettext` is [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)